# git: remove an uncessary file from commit after push

Tags: git

How can I do to remove file (f2) that should not be added in this branch?

I did:

```
git add f1
git add f2
git commit -m 'add files f'
git push origin branch0
```

Let's say that i don't want to delete it from git, i want just to not add in a special commit.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want it to be _ignored_ from future commits? Add it you your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @MattClark no not what i mean, i did a commit and added file by mistake, i want to leave this file from this commit . Hope that im clear!

Comment: You literally *can't* remove the file from *that* commit. Follow [Gursimran Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622558/1256452) to make a *new* commit that has what you'd like to have, then stop using the old commit that you don't like. Note, however, that *every* commit has *every* file: commits are snapshots, not changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do following:
Below changes will replace your previous push with new one

1. git reset HEAD^
   then do any changes you want
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "your message"
4. git push origin branch0 --force-with-lease

Comment: Not too clear! can you explain it please. @Gursmran Singh

Comment: do -> git reset HEAD^  ->this will un-stage your commit changes.
then you can do-> git checkout f2 -> this will drop the changes for f2 (if file is newly created then delete might be needed)
then -> git add . -> git commit -m "your message" -> then -> git push origin branch0 --force-with-lease.    HOPE THIS IS CLEAR NOW

Comment: it's more clear now thank you! how can i do git reset HEAD^ commit_number? please?

Comment: just go to that branch where you wrongly added a file. and do git reset HEAD^(here ^ represents 1 previous commit, ^^ for 2 previous commit, ^^^ for 3 previous commits and so on

Comment: Your proposition drops the file entirely !! :/